# Problems with GetView, Views, Bitmaps and multithreading

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am currently trying to make the scrolling of my GridView smoother by moving some work from the UI-thread into other threads, but I get strange behavior: sometimes one image is drawn to more then one view. I am using Xamarin (C#).

Below you can find the simplyfied version of my current code. LoadShowImageAsync is called from within the GetView() in my gridview Adapter. If I call LoadShowImageDoWork() singlethreaded everything is fine but when I call it via the ThreadPool it shows the strange behaviour.
In the debuglogs I see that the method is left after decoding the image and the RunOnUiThread stuff is executed combined for several images later. Then some other Images gets decoded and then RunOnUiThread stuff is done combined for them. I guess that somehow the bitmap content gets mixed up here.

Has anyone an idea what I can do to make it work multithreaded?

```
public class LoadImageAsyncDatas {
    public int ImageId { get; private set;}
    public ImageView ImageView { get; private set;}

    public LoadImageAsyncDatas (ImageView imageView,int imageId) {
        ImageId = imageId;
        ImageView = imageView;
    }
}

public class LoadImageAsync {

    private object locker;
    Activity activity;

    public LoadImageAsync (Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        locker = new object ();
    }

    public void LoadShowImageAsync (ImageView imageView,int imageId) {
        object stateInfo = new LoadImageAsyncDatas (imageView, imageId);
        // call LoadShowImageDoWork() either multithreaded (strange behaviour) or single threaded (works)
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (new WaitCallback (LoadShowImageDoWork), stateInfo);
        // LoadShowImageDoWork (stateInfo);
    }

    private void LoadShowImageDoWork (object stateInfo) {
        lock (locker) {     // lock is only for debugging
            LoadImageAsyncDatas imageData = stateInfo as LoadImageAsyncDatas;

            byte[] imageBytes = LoadFileByImageId(imageData.ImageId);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray (imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length, myBitmapOptions);

            activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {
                imageData.ImageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Jens

Comment: Are you aware that ANdroid's ListView recycle its children in order to keep low memory ?

Comment: yes, I am. But the ImageView is stored in imageData.ImageView, so I should have a strong reference to it...

Comment: i did use WeakReference in my "real" code, but weakReference.IsAlive is always true in my case, which doesn't really help

Answer (score 0):

If you want each bitmap in an Android list control to be unique then you must manage unique bitmaps for each visible "cell" on the display. If you try to re-use a bitmap that is currently being used to display another cell, you'll change both of them. For example, if you use a single bitmap to handle all of the GetView() requests of the list, each time you update the bitmap, all of the cells in the list which were set to that bitmap object will display the new bitmap. In my applications I manage this situation by setting a unique ID value (the list index) into the ImageView object. When a GetView() request is sent, I can then tell if the bitmap has been re-used and now needs to display new information. It also allows me to know when I need to create a new bitmap versus re-use an existing one.

Use these two functions to manage the IDs of your bitmaps set into your ImageViews:

```
ImageView.setTag()
ImageView.getTag()
```

Comment: can you provide some example code?
I get the bitmap from BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray and can not really control if it is new or already used

Comment: BitmapFactory creates new bitmaps, so you will need to recycle the old ones. The android garbage collector doesn't automatically do it for you.